# How to efficiently avoid adding duplicate members to cryptographic accumulators?

Tags: accumulators

I'm looking for a more efficient way to avoid adding duplicate members to a cryptographic accumulator.
Currently, I require users to provide a non-membership proof, and only if the proof is valid, adding to the accumulator is allowed.
Is there a way to merge the check-and-add steps into one step?

Additionally, I've noticed that generating non-membership proofs is not efficient for an RSA accumulator containing thousands of members. Is there a method to improve the efficiency?